# summing up the values in a column from groupedby dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my pandas.DataFrame:

```
    a  b
0   1  5
1   1  7
2   2  3
3   1  3
4   2  5
5   2  6
6   1  4
7   1  3
8   2  7
9   2  4
10   2  5
```

I want to create a new DataFrame that will contain the data grouped by 'a' and  contains the sum of the largest 3 values for each group.

Here is the output I expect. The largest 3 values of 'b' for group 1 are 7,5 and 4, and for group 2 are 7, 6 and 5.

```
a
1  16
2  18

df.groupby('a')['b'].nlargest(3)
```

gives me this output,

```
 a    
 1  1     7
    0     5
    6     4
 2  8     7
    5     6
    10    5
```

and

```
  df.groupby('a')['b'].nlargest(3).sum()
```

gives me the total sum 34 (16+18).

How can I get the expected output with pandas.DataFrame?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Using `apply` is one way to do it.

```
In [41]: df.groupby('a')['b'].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(3).sum())
Out[41]:
a
1    16
2    18
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

Timings

```
In [42]: dff = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [43]: dff.shape
Out[43]: (11000, 2)

In [44]: %timeit dff.groupby('a')['b'].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(3).sum())
100 loops, best of 3: 2.44 ms per loop

In [45]: %timeit dff.groupby('a')['b'].nlargest(3).groupby(level='a').sum()
100 loops, best of 3: 3.44 ms per loop
```

Comment: Interesting, it seems timings depends of size of groups, see my timings. Can you test it in your pc, please?

Comment: It seems if groups are large - you have only `2` large groups and me `15` `apply` is faster.

Comment: You're right. I got 138 vs 140ms. `apply` performing marginally better for your test case.

Comment: 138 vs 140 I think it is same timing ;) So both solution are nice I think.

Comment: Thank you John. If I have longer list of the output, how can I sort it out and select the top three?

Answer (score 0):

Use double `groupby` - second by level `a` of `MultiIndex`:

```
s = df.groupby('a')['b'].nlargest(3).groupby(level='a').sum()
print (s)
a
1    16
2    18
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

But for me is nicer:

```
df.groupby('a')['b'].nlargest(3).sum(level=0)
```

thank you [`Nickil Maveli`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41187041/summing-up-the-values-in-a-column-from-groupedby-dataframe-in-pandas/41187077?noredirect=1#comment69574451_41187077).

EDIT: If need top `3` again, use [`Series.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4],
                   'b': [5, 7, 3, 3, 5, 6, 4, 3, 7, 4, 5]})

print (df)
    a  b
0   1  5
1   1  7
2   2  3
3   3  3
4   2  5
5   2  6
6   1  4
7   3  3
8   4  7
9   3  4
10  4  5


df = df.groupby('a')['b'].nlargest(3).sum(level=0).nlargest(3)
print (df)
a
1    16
2    14
4    12
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000

L2 = np.arange(100)

df = pd.DataFrame({'b':np.random.randint(20, size=N), 
                   'a': np.random.choice(L2, N)})

print (df)

In [22]: %timeit df.groupby('a')['b'].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(3).sum())
10 loops, best of 3: 125 ms per loop

In [23]: %timeit df.groupby('a')['b'].nlargest(3).groupby(level='a').sum()
10 loops, best of 3: 121 ms per loop

In [29]: %timeit df.groupby('a')['b'].nlargest(3).sum(level=0)
10 loops, best of 3: 121 ms per loop
```

---

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000

L2 = list('abcdefghijklmno')

df = pd.DataFrame({'b':np.random.randint(20, size=N), 
                   'a': np.random.choice(L2, N)})

print (df)

In [19]: %timeit df.groupby('a')['b'].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(3).sum())
10 loops, best of 3: 97.9 ms per loop

In [20]: %timeit df.groupby('a')['b'].nlargest(3).groupby(level='a').sum()
10 loops, best of 3: 96.5 ms per loop

In [31]: %timeit df.groupby('a')['b'].nlargest(3).sum(level=0)
10 loops, best of 3: 97.9 ms per loop
```

---

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000

L2 = list('abcde')

df = pd.DataFrame({'b':np.random.randint(20, size=N), 
                   'a': np.random.choice(L2, N)})

print (df)


In [25]: %timeit df.groupby('a')['b'].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(3).sum())
10 loops, best of 3: 82 ms per loop

In [26]: %timeit df.groupby('a')['b'].nlargest(3).groupby(level='a').sum()
10 loops, best of 3: 81.9 ms per loop

In [33]: %timeit df.groupby('a')['b'].nlargest(3).sum(level=0)
10 loops, best of 3: 82.5 ms per loop
```

Comment: This is useful. Y̶o̶u̶ ̶m̶i̶g̶h̶t̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶i̶n̶t̶e̶r̶e̶s̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶t̶i̶m̶i̶n̶g̶s̶ Ah, you already have them. Neat.

Comment: `df.groupby('a')['b'].nlargest(3).sum(level=0)` - slightly faster

Comment: @NickilMaveli -very nice code I think, I never see it before. Thanks.

Comment: @Ivo - I add solution for top 3 of output, please check it.